# Compute $d(x^{100},P_{\le 98})$ where $P$ is subspace of polynomials with degree $\le 98$

Tags: general-topology, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Compute $d(x^{100},P_{\le 98})$ where $P$ is subspace of polynomials with degree $\le 98$, looking at $C_{(2)}[-1,1]$, with $L_2$ norm.

I tried to look at a general polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{98} a_ix^i$ and use $\|f-g\|=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)} \, dx$ but this is too excessive and I can't see what it hinders. I also tried using the zero element but would end up with a non-zero result which isn't helpful much (if the questioned had asked about $x^{99}$ instead, I would have none that $\|x^{99}\|=0$ and there is no non-negative value smaller than 0). But this is not the case, so what should I do?

Edit: how about $x\in P_{\le 98}$? $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 x^{100} \, dx = \left.\frac{x^{102}} {102}\right|_{-1}^1=0$. Is it correct?

Comment: I think you meant to write $$||f-g||^2 = \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx.$$

Comment: I think you should project onto $P$ using the inner product of the Hilbert space.

Comment: Looking at the notes, one remark related the metric I showed above, but for $C_2[-1,1]$ (Is it the same?) What are the conditions according to which you know the metric is subtraction? I really want to understand...

Comment: That is not the metric, but rather the inner product (I'm assuming we are talking about real functions so I won't write complex conjugates)
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x) dx.$$
The norm of a function is defined as $||f|| = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}$, and this induces a distance (or metric)
$$\text{dist}(f,g)=||f-g|| = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1|f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx}.$$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I found $x={x\over \sqrt{67}}$ to be useful and give zero. I hope I am close.

Comment: Oh, I am going to need complex for that.

Comment: You shouldn't get zero. The only way that $\|f\|_2=0$ is if $f=0$ almost everywhere and since we are dealing with polynomials, which are continuous, $\|f\|_2=0$ if and only if $f=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elaboration on angryavian's comment.

The $L^2$-distance is defined by $$\|f-g\|_2=\left(\int_{-1}^1|f(z)-g(z)|^2\,dz\right)^{1/2}$$ with inner product given by $$\langle f,g\rangle_2=\int_{-1}^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx.$$

You will want to work with projection onto $P_{\le 98}$. Since we are working with finite-dimensional spaces, the point in $P_{\le 98}$ that is closest to some other point is the projection onto this subspace. Clearly, $P_{\le 98}$ is spanned by elements of the form $x^n$ for $n=0,1,\dots, 98$. So, you want to find a monic, degree 100 polynomial $P$ with zero coefficient of $x^{99}$ and such that $\int_{-1}^1P(x)x^n\,dx=0$ for each $n=0,\dots, 98$. This is just a system of 99 linear equations in 99 variables.

The point of $P_{98}$ which is closest to $x^{100}$ is $Q(x)=P(x)-x^{100}$, so you just find the distance between $Q$ and $x^{100}$.

In your edit, you integrated wrong and forgot to square the integrand.

Comment: Is there some way of finding such a polynomial? I find it really exhausting.

Comment: The equation is $$2\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{99}\\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 &\frac{1}{5} & \cdots & \frac{1}{99} & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
0 & \frac{1}{99} & 0& \frac{1}{101}& \cdots &  \frac{1}{195} & 0\\
\frac{1}{99} & 0 & \frac{1}{101} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{197}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a_0\\a_1\\ \vdots\\ a_{97}\\ a_{98}\end{array}\right)+2\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{1}{101}\\ 0\\ \frac{1}{103}\\ \vdots\\ \frac{1}{197}\end{array}\right)=0.$$

Comment: I don't see a nice way to invert this, but it reduces the question into a simple linear algebra computation that a computer could perform.

Comment: I should have said that the polynomial $P$ has the form $P(z)=z^{100}+a_{98}z^{98}+\dots+ a_0$.